# bootstrap modal tabs not changing content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple modals in one html file for my Rails application and 2 modals have tabs in them. The issue I am facing is that for one of the modals the tabs do not change content when I click through them. I know its not a modal specific problem as I realized that if I move the code around (put one modal before the other), the tabs work, only for one modal at a time though.

Specifically, the problem is in showModal and addStudent, if I put anything before addStudent, the tabs for that modal work, but addStudent tabs dont work. Same vice versa if I put the modal after. I can't seem to figure out how to to fix this or why it is happening. Here is a collapsed version of the code:

```
<!-- Birthday Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="birthday" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

<!-- Reports Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="reports" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

<!-- addStudent modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addStudent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

<!-- Show Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

<!-- Support Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="support" role="dialog">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to make a codepen or jsfiddle for your problem? It really helps to customize the answer for you.

Comment: http://codepen.io/alvinlau/pen/grXNXq - Iv added the full code for both modals that are causing the issue, addStudent modal seems to be the primary cause of the problem. I thought maybe a missing <div> could be causing it but every closing tag lines up. Thanks.

Comment: On line ten you have
    <%= form_for(Kid.new, :html => {class: "form-horizontal container-fluid", id: "FormOne"}) do |f| %> plus other tags with the <% ofrmat...this is breaking the html for me

Comment: But I think your main problem is that all of the tabs and tab-content sections need unique IDs or else the tab navigation will be confused.

Comment: Wow I would have never thought of it, because I copy/pasted the modal when making the new one. But thank you, it works perfectly now! Great and clear example as well. Cheers :)

Comment: Awesome...glad it works for you. I certainly banged my head up against the wall when first trying to use tabs in bootstrap. How much time is wasted in our lives on very simple things!!!